# How to do the same as clicking Start, then the power icon, then "Shut down" in Win32

Tags: windows, winapi

In Windows 10 and 11 (I'm not sure about previous versions) if you click *Start*, then the power icon, then *Shut down* Windows shuts down then on the next power on it:

- does a fast start
- automatically logs in the last interactive user and locks the session
- starts any apps in the Start menu Startup folder but does not start any other apps that were running at the time of the shutdown.

I am trying to do this using the Win32 api but I cannot find out how to do it. The `ExitWindowsEx()` function has an option for fast start but no option to log the user back in at the next boot. The `InitiateSystemShutdownEx()` function is even more limited.

I note that the command `shutdown /sg` shuts down then automatically logs in the last user at the next boot, but it does not support fast start (hybrid shutdown) and it restarts all apps that were previously running, not just apps from the Startup folder.

I assume *Start, power, Shutdown* must be using some other method to shutdown Windows. If anyone knows how to reproduce this please let me know.

Comment: InitiateShutdown (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-initiateshutdownw) ?

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks, but `InitiateShutdown()` has no flags that `ExitWindowsEx()` doesn't have i.e. I can't see any way to use it to reproduce what *Start/Shut down* does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fast startup and hibernation**

First of all, note that hibernate and fast startup are different. In short, fast startup is some hibrid state between hibernation and normal shutdown. More about that in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/distinguishing-fast-startup-from-wake-from-hibernation) article.

To enter the computer to hibernation use `SetSuspendState` win api.

Fast startup can be performed by passing the `EWX_HYBRID_SHUTDOWN` to the `ExitWindowsEx`.

**Application restart**

You may register applications for restart using `RegisterApplicationRestart` and then pass the flag `EWX_RESTARTAPPS` to `ExitWindowsEx` as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/recovery/registering-for-application-restart) article suggests.

**Automatic logon**

There are different ways to logon the current user after a restart. For example using the registry - `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\AutomaticRestartSignOnConfig`. For more about it and on other options that may suits your use case better refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/component-updates/winlogon-automatic-restart-sign-on--arso-) article.

Comment: Aha, thanks, the link in your answer led me to the EWX_ARSO flag for ExitWindowsEx. This is not mentioned in the Win32 documentation but it is defined in winuser.h and setting it for ExitWindowsEx gives exactly the same result as Start, power, shut down.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has run into this problem the solution is the use the (undocumented) `EWX_ARSO` flag with `ExitWindowsEx()`.

The documentation for `ExitWindowsEx()` states:

```
Syntax
BOOL ExitWindowsEx(
  [in] UINT  uFlags,
  [in] DWORD dwReason
);
Parameters
[in] uFlags

The shutdown type. This parameter must include one of the following values.

EWX_HYBRID_SHUTDOWN
0x00400000
Beginning with Windows 8:  You can prepare the system for a faster startup by combining the EWX_HYBRID_SHUTDOWN flag with the EWX_SHUTDOWN flag.
etc
```

It describes half a dozen flags that determine how Windows is shut down, but it does not mention the `EWX_ARSO` flag and indeed Googling for it finds no useful information. However the flag is defined in `winuser.h` and including it gives exactly the same behaviour as clicking *Start, power, Shut down* in Windows.